# Recurrence Relation for a loop

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence

The question is to set up a recurrence relation to find the value given by the algorithm. The answer should be in teta() terms.

```
foo = 0;

for int i=1 to n do
    for j=ceiling(sqrt(i)) to n do
        for k=1 to ceiling(log(i+j)) do
             foo++
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, tag it as such.

Comment: tagged homework, what do you mean by reformat. I'm new to this platform. Is there sth I need to use to format?

Comment: So, now, what's the specific question? You'd like us to post the final solution? -- What does this `foo` stand for?

Comment: I modified it foo is the variable to increment at every step. I would like to have a recurrence relation "f(n) = blah blah" which is the final value of the foo after all iterations

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but here goes.

Second loop executes `1 - sqrt(1) + 2 - sqrt(2) + ... + n - sqrt(n) = n(n+1)/2 - n^1.5` times => `O(n^2)` times. See [here](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=228193) for a discussion that `sqrt(1) + ... + sqrt(n) = O(n^1.5)`.

We've established that the third loop will get fired `O(n^2)` times. So the algorithm is asymptotically equivalent to something like this:

```
for i = 1 to n do
    for j = 1 to n do
        for k = 1 to log(i+j) do
            ++foo
```

This leads to the sum `log(1+1) + log(1+2) + ... + log(1+n) + ... + log(n+n)`. `log(1+1) + log(1+2) + ... + log(1+n) = log(2*3*...*(n+1)) = O(n log n)`. This gets multiplied by `n`, resulting in `O(n^2 log n)`.

So your algorithm is also `O(n^2 log n)`, and also `Theta(n^2 log n)` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: +1: Theta(n^2 log n) looks right and for not handing over the recurrence relation...